# How to separate values in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a text file that contains gas price information by date. The format of the file is:

Month-Day-Year:Price

Example: [GasPrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyCSl.png)

I need to accomplish 2 tasks:

(1) Separate the input into -- month, day, year, price

(2) Calculate the average gas price per year and per month.

Can someone point me in the right direction, because I'm new to Stack Overflow and coding?

Comment: Can you include the data as text here and add an example of your desired output?

Comment: Just try to write the code and we will help out through the mistakes. Directly giving the solution might not help you develop the skills required

Comment: include a data sample as a text file so we one can provide a solution without having to recreate a sample

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   Please familiarize with these FAQs and repost your question -- (1) How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and (2) Why is voting important? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote.  -- Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

This problem is so simple it doesn't even warrant using regular expression.
The beauty of python is that you can always economize on code.
your starting point is the separator `:` (I recreated your set and put it in a .txt file)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table("stack_example.txt", sep = ":", header = -1, names = 
["date","val"])
```

[image]

```
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).month
df['year']  = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year
df.head()
```

[image]

finally

```
df_grp = df.loc[:,["val","month","year"]].groupby(["month", "year"]).mean()
df_grp
```

[image]

without counting `.head()` and `import pandas` this is 4 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('/path/to/file','r') as f:
   fullfile = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
datesprices=[(x.split(':')[0], x.split(':')[1]) for x in fullfile]
```

This code reads the file into a list called fullfile, strips newline characters, and puts the prices corresponding to the dates into a list of tuples using the split function. If you have questions comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv` stdlib module, which is good for all sorts of character-delimited file parsing.

```
import csv

with open("path/to/file") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=":")
    for date, gas_price in reader:
        # do whatever
```